Why is my responsive dropdown menu not disappearing (but shifting right) when I click the hamburger menu?
I was trying to build a responsive burger menu that appears and disappears (by onclick toggling active class in js) but now it is not disappearing but it is just on the right of my page (now there is a scrollbar too).
What did I mess up? I was literally just following a tutorial but I can't figure out where I went wrong. Please help!


const hamburgerMenu = document.querySelector(".hamburger-menu");
const nav = document.querySelector(".nav");

hamburgerMenu.addEventListener("click", () => {
  nav.classList.toggle("active")
});
/* NAVIGATION */

.nav-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.nav-container .logo {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.nav-ul {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.nav-container,
.nav-ul {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1.6rem;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.hamburger-menu {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default for larger screens */
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
}


/* NAVIGATION MEDIA QUERY*/

@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .nav-container .logo {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    z-index: 2;
  }
  .nav {
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 2rem;
  }
  .nav-ul {
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: .6rem;
  }
  .hamburger-menu {
    display: block;
    z-index: 2;
  }
  .nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -100%;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 6rem;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #4D4DDB;
    color: white;
    transition: 0.15s ease-in-out;
  }
  .nav.active {
    right: 0;
  }
}
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="header">
  <div class="nav-container">
    <span class="logo lato-bold">DacHOW<i class="fa-regular fa-circle-question"></i></span>
    <nav class="nav">
      <ul class="nav-ul">
        <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">First steps</a></li>
        <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">BAMF/Asylum</a></li>
        <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Bezahlkarte</a></li>
        <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Health</a></li>
        <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">School</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <span class="hamburger-menu material-symbols-outlined"><i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i>  
       </div>
    </div>



I tried to check the nav class in particular and I think the problem is not with its active state but the default state (with the right: -100%). In the tutorial it was this way though and it "disappeared" instead of well... being next to the page.

Don't push the nav out of view using right: -100%. Use display: none instead.

If you want that fancy animation on opening, use transform and fade between the states using transition.

looks like the snippet is not replicating the issue

thanks, I just changed it to display:none and it worked :)

Remove position absolute and use transform: translate(-100%,0) and add as well in the parent nav overflow:hidden; you can use transition that way

You can also use position:fixed instead absolute to avoid the scrolling bar ;)
